# MonoDevelop unable to find shared libs on (L)Ubuntu

Tags: c#, opencv, ubuntu, monodevelop, emgucv

Im trying to use EmguCV to do some image processing with MonoDevelop. I can build the project but if I try to debug/run it from inside MonoDevelop, I get a `DllNotFoundException` saying it cannot find libdl.so. If I run the compiled program directly (with `mono emgucv_test.exe`) everything works fine.
This is a console app, I got very similar behaviour for a Gtk# test project where it said, it couldnt find libgdiplus.so. I can find both libs however with `ldconfig -p |grep libgdiplus`.
All of this leads me to believe, that this is neither a problem with missing libs, EmguCV/OpenCV nor mono but with MonoDevelop.

I tried setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable in the projects run configuration, that didn't help. I was unable to find anything related online and don't know what else I could try. What is the problem and how can I fix this? This is just a test app, for the real project Im going to need to be able to properly debug with MonoDevelop.

Im running MonoDevelop 6.1.1 (flatpak version) in Lubuntu 16.10 (also tested in Ubuntu 16.04) in a VirtualBox VM and I installed the latest mono (v4.6.1).

**Update**
I just tested this with MonoDevelop installed with the `monodevelop` package (version 5.10). With this it works.
I know nothing about flatpak, but I've read somewhere, that it is kind of a sandbox environment for apps. If this is true, could the problems I experience be due to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically expected.

As you theorized, the issue is that FlatPak applications run in a sandbox. FlatPak MonoDevelop can only see:

- Its own /usr - provided by org.freedesktop.Runtime
- Its own /app - where everything built for the package goes - e.g. Gtk#, FSharp, libgdiplus, Mono
- Your home directory
- /dev, for things like /dev/kvm, if we ever need that for some reason

It can't see anything outside those locations.

To explore, you can use `flatpak run --command=bash com.xamarin.MonoDevelop` which will give you a shell inside the runtime so you can see the actual contents.

If what you want isn't bundled, you have three choices:

1. Grab it from NuGet, if it exists there
2. One way or another, provide it somewhere in /home
3. Build your own MonoDevelop, sans FlatPak's containerization, and use that instead

Using a sandbox for GUI apps is a trend in Linux desktop apps, including IDEs (e.g. GNOME Builder has the exact same limitations)

Comment: well, that sucks to be honest, but thank you for the explanation